# Send string from native C dynamic library (.so) to VB .net in Mono Linux

Tags: c, vb.net, mono, dynamic-linking, raspberry-pi2

I want to send a string from unmanaged C-code to managed VB .Net that runs at a Raspberry pi running Linux and mono. I debug the Dynamic C library (.so) in netbeans by calling the dynamic C library from c++. This works like a charm, but when I call the same function from VB .Net running in Linux with Mono it returns a empty string.

Here's the code

```
C
void HelloCstr(/*OUT*/ char* hello)
{
    string s = ("Hello World");
    strcpy(hello, s.c_str());
}
```

_

```
C++
std::string ss;
HelloCstr((char*)ss.c_str()); // ss is filled with "Hello World"
```

_

```
VB .Net

<DllImport("libDllTest", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Public Shared Sub HelloCstr(str As System.Text.StringBuilder)
End Sub


Public Shared Function HelloWorld() As String
    Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder(200)
    HelloCstr(sb) //After this call sb.Length == 0
    Return sb.ToString() // this returns an empty string
End Function
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging I realized that I did not add the .so library in a correct way to Linux. The above code works. I hope that It'll will be of help to someone..